# Converting dictionary to multi-dimensional array?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-engineering

I have dictionary which stores colored image data for 4 classes. Each image is 256* 256 * 3.
My dictionary has 4 keys named plane, bird, dog and cat. Each of this key in the dictionary has 50 arrays of dimension 256* 256* 3 (50 images of each class as an 3-D array, total 200 images). I want to convert this data structure into 200 * 3* 256* 256 shape array which has extracted label from dictionary key. How can I achieve this easiest way? I tried numpy reshape but did not work.

Comment: Instead of describing your data, can you show us even a small bit of the data structure in code?

Comment: @LaurenBoland I thought it was pretty clear to be honest.

Comment: Data and code are far clearer if you actually show it, instead of describing it with words that might be left up for interpretation. But I look forward to seeing your answer. :)

Comment: @LaurenBoland As it is multi dimensional, i had no idea how to represent it here, hence I tried to explain it as above. I can show you 2-D, but not sure about 3-D or in this case I have to convert it to 4-D.

Answer (score 2):

So I'm assuming your data setup looks something like this (obviously with real data instead of random data):

```
classes = ["plane", "bird", "dog", "cat"]
images = {
     k: [np.random.uniform(size=(256, 256, 3))
         for _ in range(50)]
     for k in classes
}
```

What we can do is the following:

```
X = np.concatenate([images[k] for k in classes], axis=0)
y = np.concatenate([[i] * len(images[k]) for i, k in enumerate(classes)])
```

Which gives what you want, I believe:

```
>>> X.shape
(200, 256, 256, 3)

>>> y.shape
(200,)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works, one follow-up question though,  instead of (200, 256, 256, 3), would it be possible to have it as (200 ,3, 256,256).

Comment: @atp Check out `np.swapaxes`.